# Repeatedly interpreting polar coordinates as Cartesian

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

Start with a Cartesian point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, convert it to polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$
($\phi$ in radians),
and then reinterpret $(r,\phi)$ as $(x,y)$, i.e., set
$$(x,y) = (r,\phi) \;.$$
And now repeat.
Here is a typical example of the results.
The red points represent starting $(x,y)$ points (random within $[\pm 3]^2$), and the blue lines track
(in this case) $8$ iterations:

---

[image: PolarCartesian3]

---

It forms a curious and attractive pattern deserving
of explanation.
Clearly there is a "circling" around $(1,0)$, but the circling is not
quite circular.

> ***Q1***. What is a succinct explanation of the overall pattern?
>
> ***Q2***. What is the limiting shape of the vortex surrounding $(1,0)$?

Comment: Well, in terms of complex numbers, you're iterating the map $x+iy \mapsto xe^{iy} = e^{\log{x}+iy}$.

Comment: @Chappers isn't it $ x + iy \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + i \arctan{\frac{y}{x}} $ ?